# Spring security custom filter (reason for creating AuthenticationManager bean while it already exists)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, servlet-filters

When we use a custom filter we need to inject a bean of type `AuthenticationManager`.

As far as I remember, if we use the default filter then Spring automatically provides Authentication Manager. This leads me to the conclusion that there is already an `AuthenticationManager` bean in the Spring context (from my understanding).

But the problem is that my assumption is not true. I have to create and inject a bean of `AuthenticationManager` to the filter.

What is wrong with my assumption? Why do we need to crate a bean while it is already present?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring uses `AuthenticationManager` to find appropriate authentication provider but didn't register `AuthenticationManager` as a bean by default. see the source code of `HttpSecurityConfiguration` class.

```
@Bean(HTTPSECURITY_BEAN_NAME)
@Scope("prototype")
HttpSecurity httpSecurity() throws Exception {
    WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.LazyPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.LazyPasswordEncoder(
            this.context);
    AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationBuilder = new WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.DefaultPasswordEncoderAuthenticationManagerBuilder(
            this.objectPostProcessor, passwordEncoder);
    authenticationBuilder.parentAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
    HttpSecurity http = new HttpSecurity(this.objectPostProcessor, authenticationBuilder, createSharedObjects());
    // @formatter:off
    http
        .csrf(withDefaults())
        .addFilter(new WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter())
        .exceptionHandling(withDefaults())
        .headers(withDefaults())
        .sessionManagement(withDefaults())
        .securityContext(withDefaults())
        .requestCache(withDefaults())
        .anonymous(withDefaults())
        .servletApi(withDefaults())
        .apply(new DefaultLoginPageConfigurer<>());
    http.logout(withDefaults());
    // @formatter:on
    return http;
}

private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
    return (this.authenticationManager != null) ? this.authenticationManager
            : this.authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
}
```

as you can see it register an authentication manager builder in `HttpSecurity`. later in `HttpSecurity` class it will use this builder to build an authentication manager and register it in shared objects [see method `beforeConfigure()` in `HttpSecurity`].

```
@Override
protected void beforeConfigure() throws Exception {
    setSharedObject(AuthenticationManager.class, getAuthenticationRegistry().build());
}
```

and whenever it needs authentication manager uses `HttpSecurity` to get that, like the following:

```
AuthenticationManager authenticationManager = http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManager.class);
```

Comment: Thanks man much appreciated. You are a life saver.